# How to connect QT and MariaDB. driver not loaded

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, mariadb, qt-creator

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Same "QMYSQL driver not loaded" error.

But others people see the QMYSQL in the "QSqlDatabase: available drivers" message.

Why I don't even have it?

Comment: You should build **QMYSQL** driver by yourself. You can see a guide to building it on Windows [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows). And please, use code blocks for code, not images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is to download the connector installer, depending on the version of the compiler you are using, 64 or 32 bits, for c from here:
https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-c/

locate the connector installation folder and run these commands.

cd% QTDIR% \ qtbase \ src \ plugins \ sqldrivers

qmake - MYSQL_INCDIR = "C: / Program Files / MySQL / MySQL Connector C 6.1 / include" MYSQL_LIBDIR = "C: / Program Files / MySQL / MySQL Connector C 6.1 / lib"

mingw32-make

mingw32-make install

Here you can see the official Qt documentation.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qmysql

and with that you would have everything ready, good luck.

note.
don't forget to include the sql module in your .pro file.